# Internal DNS with BIND, how to resolve one IP address differently?

Tags: bind, internal-dns

I have an internal DNS (it is completely internal, ie. the network is not connected to Internet) for a group of networks. They are set up as follows:

- Each network has a different address range of `10.x.0.0/16` and its own domain `domainx` (it is a top-level domain) - for example network `10.1.0.0/16` has `domain1` (all hosts in this network have DNS names `somehost.domain1`)
- For each network/domain, host `ns.domainx` (`10.x.1.1`) is a DNS server that handles both forward zone `domainx` and reverse zone `x.10.in-addr.arpa`
- These networks are not interconnected, except of a special multi-homed server that has connectivity to all these networks (and my question is about that server in fact) - but it does not route packets between those networks, it only can communicate with each of them. It is **by design**, each network is designed to be operated separately and standalone.
- Therefore, the DNS server in each network knows only about its domain; it doesn't know (and **should not know**) anything about domains from other networks.
- However, the multi-homed server I mentioned earlier needs to have working DNS resolution for addresses in all these networks. By requirement, I can't touch anything in any of the networks, in particular their DNS servers. I can only modify configuration of the multi-homed server.
- So I set up BIND on the multi-homed server that just defines zone `.` as "master", and the zone file contains the following records:

  ```
  1.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN    NS    ns.domain1.
  domain1.              IN    NS    ns.domain1.
  ns.domain1.           IN    A     10.1.1.1

  2.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN    NS    ns.domain2.
  domain2.              IN    NS    ns.domain2.
  ns.domain2.           IN    A     10.2.1.1

  3.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN    NS    ns.domain3.
  domain3.              IN    NS    ns.domain3.
  ns.domain3.           IN    A     10.3.1.1
  ```

  and so on for all networks.

Everything works OK, but there is one small issue.

Sometimes the DNS server for a particular network is down. In these networks, the DNS server being down is **not** considered a failure - it is just a normal operating state that can happen. It is expected and normal that there will be no DNS resolution for that particular network at that time.

But there is one particular IP address in network 1 (say, `10.1.10.10`) that I want **always** to resolve to a domain name - even when the DNS for network 1 is down. So it must be resolved by the local server, not delegated to the server for network 1. Actually, it is also acceptable that NXDOMAIN will be returned as a response to the query for this address (if this is easier to configure), but the response must be returned immediately, without trying to contact the DNS server for network 1 - the delay when that server is down is exactly what we want to avoid.

And I don't know how to do this.

Adding a PTR record for `10.10.1.10.in-addr.arpa.` to the `.` zone file does not work - it seems to be simply ignored, and when the DNS for network 1 is not working, `10.1.10.10` is not resolved.

How to make this address resolve locally?

Comment: This sounds like a X-Y problem to me. The normal way to handle DNS server outage is to have multiple DNS-servers. There's furthermore no reason one server can't have multiple views, so that isolation can be upheld with only one DNS-server serving multiple nets.

Comment: @vidarlo I have simplified the setup for the sake of this question - in fact there are usually 3 DNS servers for each network. But it is **expected** that **all** of them may be down. This is the way the network operates. The single address I'm interested in is "special" (sorry, I can't disclose details) and therefore should be handled on the multi-homed server level even if all "subordinate" DNS servers are down.

Comment: @vidarlo Also, as I wrote, it is **by design** that each network is independent, so there can't be a single DNS server serving multiple nets. The networks **have to** not know anything about each other. The multi-homed server is an additional layer we added. It does not exist "in the field". You can imagine the entire networks (including their DNS servers) being 3rd party products that you have no control over and can't touch anything there. You control only the multi-homed server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It was actually simple. It was sufficient to add `10.10.1.10.in-addr.arpa` as another "master" zone to my `named.conf` file, with the zone file being `named.empty` ie. the default file included in BIND configuration to serve zone `0.in-addr.arpa`.

Now the query for `10.1.10.10` gives the answer that the address has no PTR record, regardless whether the DNS server for `10.1.0.0/16` is up or down. That eliminates the delay when resolving the address, which is sufficient for me. Of course I could define a separate zone file for this zone instead of `named.empty` and add in this zone file a PTR record for `@` to make the IP address actually resolve to some domain name, but I have no need for this right now.